# IntelliJ Scratches not In Drop Down

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ 2016.1 and wondering if where to find a list of "Scratches"? In Android Studio it was in the drop down Project menu.

I have looked through all the settings and cannot find it.

Do Scratches ONLY apply to Java? Or can I use them for PHP/Python?
I can use a HOTKEY can create a Scratch, but I dont know how to get it on my menu.

Does anyone know?

**@Regarding the first answer**, here is what I have, Im baffled (Im on Linux if it matters)!
[image]

And this which doesn't expand:
[image]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/scratches.html#rename_scratch

Answer (score 2):

If you click the sideways triangle after Packages you can select scratches.

[image: Triangle]

Then check the Scratches checkbox.
[image: Menu with scratches in]

Or you can bring up the Select Target menu by pressing Alt F1 and then navigating to Project View and then Scratches.

Scratches can be in any language.

[image: Scraches Menu Option]

Comment: Thank you for the screen shots, I upvoted this yet I had to post pictures -- I dont understandt why I dont have that arrow on the side, nor my project menu expand. Perhaps I broke something with a plugin? I just added Python, Php, and Node, a theme also.